# How to refresh page without reloading after closing dialog in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to angular Material and I am working on my first project using it, however I have come to realize that after closing the dialog the page does not refresh, therefore you cannot see the new updates, either a new record you added, a record you updated or deleted, you cannot see it unless you either reload the page manually or via the following code:

```
openDialog(projectId:number):void{
  
  const dialogRef = this.dialog
  
  .open(UpdateProjectComponent, {
      data:{id: projectId}
  })


  .afterClosed()
  .subscribe((reloadOrNot:boolean)=>{
    
    if(reloadOrNot) window.location.reload();
})
```

if I change my code as follows nothing happens:

```
openDialog(projectId:number):void{
  
  const dialogRef = this.dialog
  
  .open(UpdateProjectComponent, {
      data:{id: projectId}
  })


  .afterClosed()
  .subscribe((reloadOrNot:boolean)=>{
    
   if(reloadOrNot) this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.projects = data;
      }
    )

})
```

In the updateProjectComponent all I have is the reactive form to create the form programatically, a method to get the project by id and a method to update. All of these methods work, they do their jobs correctly, my only problem is that once I close the dialog the projects page is not refresh, unless I reload it, which is what I am trying to avoid.

I am calling a Java backend that provides all of the existing projects, however as mentioned before when clicking on submit button in the dialog page, the dialog closes but the projects page does not refresh the data. What would be the best way to handle this without the reload code?

Comment: how is `projects` been handled in the template HTML?

Comment: Is your component set to ChangeDetection.OnPush?

Comment: The UpdateProjectComponent component is a component separate from the projectComponent.

Comment: I added ChangeDetection.OnPush in the projectsComponent, however when I close the dialog (updateprojectcomponent) nothing happens. I am forced to reload the page to see the changes. All methods work but the refresh part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we don't see the rest of your code but changes to `this.projects = data` aren't registered with Angular Change Detection and your template does not refresh. For debugging we need more relevant code which deals with `this.projects`.

However there are ways to run change dedection cycle.

Using spread:

```js
this.projects = ...data;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823904/15439733

Using CD ref

```js
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.projects = data;
this.cd.dedectChanges();
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Configure `OnPush`->`Default` (or remove this line altogether to use Default)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy#OnPush

Comment: I added the changes above in the projectComponent, however when I close the dialog (updateprojectComponent) nothing happens, I still need to reload the page to see the changes.

Comment: You seem to be using `updateForm` I bet you need to update form control values with `data`.

Comment: should ChangeDetection.OnPush be added on projectsComponent or updateprojectcomponent (dialog)? I added it in projectsComponent but did not work.

Comment: Joosep, in the updateProjectComponent (dialog) I am populating the form using the data and it works. The idea is that a user click on a project and then the project id is sent to the dialog page where I get the data associated to that project id (that's working well), when users click on the submit button to update the record, the update works but I need to refresh the projectComponent page to see it.

Comment: Joosep, I added the ChangeDetection.OnPush in the projectComponent and additionally in the openDialog method in the afterClosed() I added the code where I populate the table using mat-table which uses a datasource. That fixed the problem and now is refreshing correctly without reloading. Thanks.

Comment: openDialog(projectId:number):void{
  
  const dialogRef = this.dialog
  
  .open(UpdateProjectComponent, {
      data:{id: projectId}
  })


  .afterClosed()
  .subscribe((reloadOrNot:boolean)=>{
    
    if(reloadOrNot) {
      
       //Assigning data to dataSource
       this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(
        data=>{
          this.dataSource.data = data;
        }
      )

      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }

  })